# UITableView cornerRadius with border performance issues on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, scroll, cornerradius

I have some interesting notice with scrolling performance on `UITableView` with `cornerRadius`, `borderWidth` and `borderColor` enabled.

```
self.tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.f;
self.tableView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
self.tableView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
```

If I remove `borderWidth` and `borderColor` than scrolling gets 60 FPS no problem. As long as I add those two properties to layer FPS drops.

Does anyone have a suggestion or explanation why this strange behavior happens?

Many Thanks!

Comment: Because it needs more drawing operations.

Comment: I think so. By setting `borderWidth` and `borderColor` it adds extra operations to draw border. Same for `cornerRadius`.

Comment: Why would that be a problem cos border is not scrolling, only cells are... ?

Comment: do you have any shadows as well?

Comment: Hm, i've noticed a huge drop on performance when using shadows (without shadowPath), but never with this one. Which method you are setting this in?

Comment: I set this in viewDidLoad method like this: self.tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.f; self.tableView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f; self.tableView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;

Comment: ok, I see, the problem occurs when border and cornerRadius are combined. You could workaround this, by adding the tableview into a container(UIView) and applying cornerRadius and border to the container.

Comment: I've done that already with no luck. Still the same sluggishness. This is kind a logical cos tableView is still wrapped inside another container and still needs to do calculations for round corners...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out that cornerRadius with borderWidth sluggish tableView performance by a lot. So instead of 10.f radius I changed to 5.f and performance has increased amazingly. Still not perfect but noticeably better...

Answer (score 6):

CALayer having shouldRasterize property for this type of performance issue.
Just set

```
self.tableView.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
```

This single line saved my lot of time and work.