# UI freeze when UIImage setting in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimage, grand-central-dispatch

I have a tableView with `UIImageView` field. I setup it in `setupCell` method which is called from `set_book` setter. Setter is called from `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`.
Here's a part of setupCell:

```
dispatch_queue_t downloadImage = dispatch_queue_create("Download Image", NULL);
    dispatch_async(downloadImage, ^{
        NSString* key = [_book.internalID stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"thumb"];
        UIImage* thumb = [[[LTImagesCacheController shared] cache] objectForKey:key];
        if (thumb == nil)
        {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                _bookImageView.layer.borderWidth = 0.0;
                _bookImageView.image = [[LTImageProvider sharedImagesProvider] imageForName:@"DefaultBook.png" cache:YES];
            });

            NSString* imageName = [[LTImagesCacheController cacheDir] stringByAppendingPathComponent:key];
            if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:imageName])
            {
                NSDictionary *attr = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSDate date], NSFileModificationDate, nil];
                [[NSFileManager defaultManager] setAttributes:attr ofItemAtPath:imageName error:nil];
                thumb = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imageName];
                [[[LTImagesCacheController shared] cache] setObject:thumb forKey:key];
            }
            else
            {
                NSString* url = _book.coverURL;
                thumb = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]];
                if (thumb != nil)
                    [[[LTImagesCacheController shared] cache] setObject:thumb forKey:key];
            }
        }

        if (thumb != nil)
        {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                _bookImageView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
                _bookImageView.image = thumb;
            });
        }
    });
dispatch_release(downloadImage);
```

When I run my app sometimes I get UI freeze for short time, less than 1 sec. What do I do wrong? I want to set DefaultBook.png as default, and if an image from _book.coverURL exists, set it. I have ~100-200 cells, thumb image size is 15-30 KB.

Comment: Whats the size of thumb image?

Comment: I have edited my post. 15-30 KB.

Comment: Did u try moving the code to `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`?

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11224955/uitableview-cornerradius-with-border-performance-issues-on-ios . May b this might help u. Try commenting `_bookImageView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;` and check.

Comment: I think it's bad idea. `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is used to create cells and reuse them with UI elements. But content as text, images etc is setted in `willDisplayCell`